# Flutter pusher_client issue

Tags: flutter, pusher

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':flutter_pusher_client' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71

Answer (score 1):

This should be resolved in [later versions](https://github.com/heywhy/flutter-pusher-client/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) of the client. You should update to version 0.2.1 or above.